# Jquery URL validation needs to contain linkedin.com

Tags: jquery, url, jquery-validate, linkedin-api

Im using jquery validation for my form, but im not used to use jQuery.

This is what i got now, it checks for a valid URL, what i want is that it checks if the URL contains linkedin.com (i want users to put in there linkedin url.

```
if(!(/^(https?|ftp):\/\//i.test(val))) {

    val = 'http://'+val;

    $(elem).val(val); 
}
return /^(https?|ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i.test(val);
```

Comment: Your regex doesn't _quite_ test that `val` is a valid URL, more that it begins with `http://`, `https://` or `ftp://` (case-insensitively)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3PuaQ/)

```
val = 'http://linkedin.com/';


if( /(ftp|http|https):\/\/?(?:www\.)?linkedin.com(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:([0-9])+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/.test(val) ) {

   alert( 'valid Linkedin URL' );

}else{

   alert( 'not valid Linkedin URL' );

}
```

Comment: It keeps saying that google.com is right. Is that because of this rule (check post)

Answer (score 2):

You could just check the variable directly using `indexOf`, for example:

```
var contains = (val.indexOf('http://www.linkedin.com') > -1); //true
```

Comment: you could just use the contains variable in a conditional.  I.e. if (contains) { // your logic here }

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is stored in `val`

```
if( (condtion1 == true) && (val.indexOf(".linkedin.com") > -1))
{

}
```